# How to send eip 1559 txn using web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, eip-1559, london

I am sending my txn like this but it is sent as legacy type only

[image]

Comment: I found the answer to this , so you have to upgrade @ethereumjs/tx and web3 and then have to use class FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction of  @ethereumjs/tx to send the transaction with new type.

Comment: <br/>
i don't use @ethereumjs/tx<br/>
only web3.sendTransaction like your sreenshot, how to use type EIP1559 ?

Answer (score 6):

Did you update your web3 version ?

As you can see on this page you need `Web3JS  >=1.5.0` :
https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/releases

Then your call seems right and you should get back a receipt specifying `type: 0x2`